On the continuity of the inverse function of a curve
Consider the following curves:
$$\phi:(-1,1) \to \mathbb{R^2}, \phi(t)=\left(t, \frac{\sin(50t)}{2}\right) 
\\\psi:\left(\frac{-3\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \to \mathbb{R^2}, \psi(t)=\left(\frac{\cos(t)}{1+\sin^2(t)}, \frac{\sin(t)\cos(t)}{1+\sin^2(t)}\right)$$
Note that both are bijections on their images.
Here is $\psi$:
In order to make the graph and the parametrization easier to understand, I have cut the domain and labeled the "initial" and "final" points A,B; clearly the domain is chosen in a way that the graph does not contain self-intersections but
$$\lim_{t\to-3\pi/2^+} \psi(t) = \lim_{t\to\pi/2^-} \psi(t) = (0,0).$$
I know that the inverse of the function defining the lemniscate is not continuous (in $(0,0)$). In fact, if it were continuous, then by definition: $$\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists \delta>0: \|\psi(t)-\psi(0)\|<\delta \implies |t|<\varepsilon.$$
However, no matter how small $\delta$ is, in every ball centered at $\psi(0)=(0,0)$ there are points of the type  $\psi(t_1)$ and $\psi(t_2)$, where $t_1$ is close to $\frac{-3\pi}{2}$ and $t_2$ is close to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.
If my intuition is correct, in a certain sense the continuity of the inverse of a function defining a graph is related to whether it is possible to "isolate" arbitrary portions of the graph with neighbourhoods. What I mean is that for $\psi$ there is no way to "zoom" the graph and eventually find a neighbourhood of the origin intersecting the lemniscate in an arc of this form:

The situation is significantly different for $\phi$:
no matter the amplitude and the frequency of the curve.
I would like to know if my intuition is correct (or there are pathological cases which show that this is not the right way of thinking) and most importantly get a rigorous proof of the fact that the inverse of $\psi$ is not continuous, since this explanation is really hand-waving. Every approach is welcomed - you may contradict the definition you prefer (I mean the topological definition involving neighbourhoods, the standard $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition etc.)

Roughly speaking, you've invented the notion of an "immersion" as opposed to an embedding -- an immersion of an interval (or circle) in the plane is a function that's locally an embedding (i.e., for small enough intervals, the restriction is actually injective. The are subtleties to immersions -- you almost always want the derivative to exist and be nonzero everywhere to avoid these. But with the keyword "immersion", you should be able to find out lots more.

@JohnHughes thanks. I have read something about the terms "immersion" and "embedding". Could you still provide more details or some references, please?

There are multiple ways to think of a curve. One is as "a set of points in the plane", and we sometimes describe such a set with an equation like
$$
x^2 + y^2 = 1.
$$
This kind of equation is called an "implicit" description because it's not immediately obvious, in general, whether there are any points $(x, y)$ that satisfy it. (Think, for example, of $x \sin(y^2) + 3x^5y^3 - \log(xy) = \pi$, where you can't just 'pick an $x$ and solve for $y$'). On the other hand, it's really easy to check whether a point $(a, b)$ is on the curve or not: you just plug $x = a, y = b$ into the defining equation and check whether you get an equality or not.
If your defining equation is a polynomial, the things you get are an example of something called an "algebraic variety", and the study of these and their generalizations is called "algebraic geometry." One thing to note is that self-crossings or sharp corners, etc.,  can often occur (as can empty sets -- look at $x^2 + y^2 = -1$, for instance). The study of such singularities is a big part of algebraic geometry, and because solving polynomial equations comes up a lot, folks often move to considering the variables as complex rather than real numbers.
I'll just note that in this case, the focus of study is on the space in which the curve sits, and your observation that every neighborhood, no matter how small, fails to look like a nice flattish arc crossing a disk, is what makes the origin of the lemniscate a singularity, and the study of what kinds of singularity can arise from implicits that happen to be polynomially described is solidly in the core of algebraic geometry.
An alternative way to think of curves is as graphs of functions (i.e., in $y = f(x)$ form). In this case, sharp corners are still possible (look at $y = |x|$), as are other problems, but things tend to be geometrically relatively nice -- the curve itself is in a nice 1-1 continuous correspondence with the real line (via $x \to (x, f(x)$), for instance, something that can't be said for the points of the circle that fit the implicit equation $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.
Function graphs are a special case of a slightly more general notion, the "parametric curve" defined by equations like
$$
x = p(t)\\
y = f(t)
$$
(Function graphs are the special case that arises when $p(t) = t$.) These are called "parametric" because of the 'parameter' $t$ that tells you where you are on the curve. A nice example of this is
$$
x = t^3 \\
y = t^2
$$
whose plot looks a little like a kid's drawing of a seagull in the distance: a soft vee with a sharp point in the center. It's easy to generate points of a parametric curve (you pick a value of $t$ and use the formulas to find $x$ and $y$), but much harder to tell whether some particular $(x, y)$ point lies on the curve or not. Example: does $(9.281, 4.41)$ lie on the curve I just described?
Parametric curves are also "nice" in the sense that there's a nice way to move between the real line (represented by $t$) and the points of the curve, namely $t \to (p(t), f(t))$. If $p$ and $f$ are 'nice' (continuous, differentiable), then this correspondence is also 'nice' in some sense. Unfortunately, it's not a 1-1 correspondence, as the parametric curve
$$
x = \cos t \\
y = \sin t
$$
shows: two different parameter values can produce the same point on the curve, so there's generally no "inverse" to this correspondence.
To get back to your discussion of the lemniscate, you've provided a parametric description of what's often described instead as an implicit curve. In many ways, your parameterization is very nice: smooth, 1-1 ... who could ask for anything more? But as you note, its inverse isn't so nice. If we think of the curve itself as a topological space $L$, with topology inherited from the euclidean plane, then the parameterization you've got is a 1-1 continuous map from $\mathbb R$ onto $L$, but lacks a continuous inverse.
This "parametric" approach is the one taken in topology and differential geometry: curves and surfaces are parameterized by intervals or patches of the euclidean plane, and to study the curve or surface, we study the properties of the parameterizing functions. You might complain that there could be many different parameterizations of the same curve, and you're right. For the circle described above, we also have the parameterization
$$
x = \sin(1 + t^3)\\
y = \cos(1 + t^3)
$$
for example. One of the challenges for a geometer is to determine the properties of a shape that are independent of the choice of parameterization.
And returning to the lemniscate, suppose we had a parameterization that actually took the real line and wrapped it along the leminscate the way that $(\cos t, \sin t)$ wraps the line onto the circle over and over. Such a parameterization would no longer be injective, but it would be surjective. And it would have another property: if we look at a small enough interval in the domain, the image of that interval would always look like your second picture (i.e., a nice arc in the plane). We could say that this parameterization was 'locally nice', where "local" here means "in the domain" rather than in the codomain. A differential geometer, looking at local properties of the shape, would say it was pretty nice. But seeing the big picture, one says "hey wait...it intersects itself!" Whitney referred to such things as "distant self intersections" (although he may not have been the first to use that term), and I find it applies nicely.
If you find "local niceness" (local in the domain!) a satisfactory notion for measuring something about a shape, then "immersions" may be a good area to study. (I happen to have done so in my dissertation.)  An example of a nice theorem about immersions is that if you have a generic smooth immersion of the projective plane in 3-space, it must have an odd number of triple points (places where three "sheets" of the surface all meet, like the three coordinate planes meeting at the origin) -- so the global topology of the image of an immersion can sometimes depend on the topology of the domain. (This theorem is due to Banchoff, ca 1971.)
If the whole notion of "crossings" just feels bad to you, there's plenty to be done studying embeddings. (Whitney's embedding theorem is a lovely example!)
And if the crossings as seen in the codomain seem fascinating, then algebraic geometry might be a good place to look.

Thank you very much for your detailed answer which clarifies much about parameterizations, embeddings and immersions. If I see what you mean, my lemniscate is an immersion because it is injective but it is not an embedding because it is not a homeomorphism on the image, as it's inverse is not continuous. Right?

And I guess my intuition regarding the "nice arc" turns out to be correct. Please, let me know if I am right

Your parameterization of the lemniscate is indeed an immersion and not an embedding. Those of use who look at the underlying set of the lemniscate and say "that's a circle that just got dropped in a funny self-intersecting way in the plane" would have parameterized it with $S^1$ as the domain, and our immersion would have had a double-point. If you think of it as your picture suggests -- an S-shaped thing whose ends just got really close -- then yours is an immersion of an interval.

I'm not sure about the "nice arc" thing. The graph of $y = \sin(\frac{1}{x}$ (together with the point $(0,0)$ has an image that has a natural 'inverse mapping to a domain', namely "project $(x, y)$ to $x$." But no neighborhood of the origin looks like your "nice arc". Math is just weird...

That's a nice counterexample. Maybe I should say that: discontinuous inverse $\implies$ no "nice arc", but the viceversa may not be true in general

Consider $\hat{\varepsilon}=\pi/2$. Let $\delta>0$ be given. Since $\lim_{t\to\pi/2^-} \psi(t) = (0,0)$, there is $\gamma \in (0, \pi/2)$ so that $\|\psi(t)\|<\delta$ whenever $0<\pi/2-t<\gamma$. Since $\gamma<\pi/2$, we have
$$t>0 \quad \text{whenever} \quad \pi/2-t<\gamma .$$ Fix $t=\psi^{-1}(x,y) \in (\pi/2-\gamma, \pi/2)$.
So we have
$$\|(x,y)\|=\|\psi(t)\|<\delta \quad \text{but} \quad |\psi^{-1}(x,y)-\psi^{-1}(0,0)|=|t+\pi/2|=t+\pi/2 >\hat{\varepsilon}.$$
So $\psi^{-1}$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

Thank you. I would appreciate if you could elaborate on my observations too
